# Unable to make POST request to add layer to GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, react

**My issue is related to post request and there is no any issue about get request**

```
export const GEOSERVER_URL:string = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/risk/datastores/scan.tekudb.local/featuretypes'
export const USERNAME:string = 'admin'
export const PASSWORD:string = 'geoserver'
export const AUTH = {
    username: USERNAME,
    password: PASSWORD
  }


 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.post(
        GEOSERVER_URL,  {
            auth: AUTH,
        },

      ).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

      console.log(result)
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

**Error**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/risk/datastores/scan.tekudb.local/featuretypes
    Request Method: POST
    Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
    Remote Address: [::1]:8080
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**How can I solve that? in get request, everything is okay but for others, it gives 401 Unauthorized error**

Comment: Are you trying to create a new feature type?

Comment: I have already solved the issue, it was related to data format. I would like to add layer from client-side to geoserver via geoserver rest/API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for adding layer via post request

```
 const addLayer = async (name: string) => {
    const updatedData = LAYER_DATA
    updatedData.featureType.name = name
    fetch(ADD_LAYER_URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      headers: HEADERS,
      body: JSON.stringify(updatedData)
    }).then((res: Response) => {
      if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
        throw new Error("Failed!");
      }
      // return res.json();
    })

    fetchData()
  }
```